# Express app.listen returns Promise { Server {} }

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have an express server running, I am running into an issue while writing unit tests. I have a startup function that connects to database, then returns a Server with app.listen(). The issue is that if I return app.listen from within an async function, I get a Promise with a server inside of it, I have tried to resolve this promise, wait for this promise, return a server from .then(). I do not want the promise I want the server.

**express.ts**

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

export { app };
```

**startup.ts**

```js
import { app } from './express';
import { sequelize } from './sequelize';

app._startup = (async() => {
  switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    case "production":
      await sequelize.authenticate();
      break;
    case "test":
      await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
      break;
    case "development":
    default:
      await sequelize.sync({ force: false });
      break;
  }
})().then(() => true);

export { app };
```

**server.ts**

```js
import { app } from './startup';

// export const server = app.listen(8080); // This works

export const server = (
  async() => {
    await app._startup;
    return app.listen(8080); // This does not work
  }
)();
```

Because the Server {} is inside a Promise {} my unit tests all fail

```
console.log(server);
// => Promise { Server { } }
```

How can I resolve this promise before exporting the server?

Comment: You can't "wait" for asynchronous tasks to be done before exports are processed.  Exports in modules only work synchronously (for now - that problem is being worked on).  You can create your server synchronously with `const server = http.createServer(app)` and export it and then only start the server with `server.listen(8080)` once your startup stuff is done.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks for your comment [@jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620)

The solution is posted below

```js
const server = createServer(app);

(async() => {
  await app._startup;
})().then(() => server.listen(8080));

export { server };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the function to complete the `async` task. Since you are defining `server` as an `async` function you can use `await` keyword to wait for it to complete. Implementation is as follows:

```
import { app } from './startup';

export const server = app.listen(8080);
export const server = await (  // use await to wait
  async() => {
    await app._startup;
    return app.listen(8080); // This does not work
  }
)();
```

Comment: You've redeclared a const variable, you have await outside of an async function, the async function has the same incapabilities as the original post